# Validate simple sql by java regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to validate a these 2 simple sql queries

```
String sql1 = "select * from table".toLowerCase();
String sql2 = "select value from table".toLowerCase();
```

using this pattern

```
String pattern = "(select)(\\s)([\\*|\\w+])(\\s)(from)(\\s\\w+)";
```

then I print the value

```
System.out.println(sql1.matches(pattern)); // true
System.out.println(sql2.matches(pattern)); // false
```

the first one is ok, but I'm getting false in the second statement. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of that you have putted the star character and word character modifier inside a character class.

When you want to choose between 2 separate word you shouldn't use character class for both.Instead you can use an logical OR (`|`) and a capture group,like following:

```
(\\*|\\w+)
```

Also note that when you put the `|` or `+` inside the character class your regex engine will escape them.

In addition if you want to match the whole of sentence you don't need to put all the words within a capture group.You can use anchors `^` and `$` for specifying the start and end of the string:

```
"^select\\s(?:\\*|\\w+)\\sfrom\\s\\w+$"
```

`(?:)` is a none capturing group.

Read more about regular expressions http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: thanks so much, problem solved also thanks for the tutorial :)

Answer (score 2):

You introduced square brackets in a group, the following line:

```
String pattern = "(select)(\\s)([\\*|\\w+])(\\s)(from)(\\s\\w+)";
```

Should be:

```
String pattern = "(select)(\\s)(\\*|\\w+)(\\s)(from)(\\s\\w+)";
```

Inside the square brackets `+` and `|` are considered as literal characters:

`[\\*|\\w+]` means a single character that is `*`, `|`, `+` or a letter.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because the + in regex is greedy, so the \w+ is consuming all the words. so it's consuming "value" "from" and "table".  You can make it "lazy" by putting question mark after '+', like:

```
([\\*|\\w+?])
```